# MSBuild: transform paths to namespaces

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have list of items like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ToCompile Include="clojure\core.clj;clojure\set.clj;clojure\zip.clj;clojure\test\junit.clj;"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

And I want to transform that to a list of items like this:

```
clojure.core clojure.set clojure.zip clojure.test.junit
```

Is there a way to do this with MSBuild transforms? I tried but I can only get at the file name; the extension and the root path, and I can change the separator. But not the path separators.

If not, any other solution that avoids using custom tasks is appreciated.

Comment: You could write a custom task in a powershell task factory, which wish is much simpler than a full C# task in its own assembly. I recommend them for very small tasks only, however. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/20/msbuild-task-factories-guest-starring-windows-powershell.aspx

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That would have been my backup solution, but the one below (although cheesy :) is much less of a hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit cheesy, but it works in MSBuild 4.0+.

```
<Target Name="Namespaces">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Cheesy>@(ToCompile -> '%(relativedir)%(filename)', ' ')</Cheesy>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="$(Cheesy.Replace(`\`, `.`))" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do it easily with fewer cheese:

<Message 
Text="$([System.String]::Copy('%(ToCompile.Identity)').Replace('.clj','').Replace('\','.'))"/>

Comment: Thanks, that looks easier indeed. But why the copy?

Comment: I believe that you can't use the `%(ToCompile.Identity)` string reference to call `.Replace` so you need to use the static method `Copy` to create a reference where `.Replace` can be used.